# How do I read the elements of an xtensor 'xexpression' object that is returned from a call to xt::load_csv()?

Tags: c++, xtensor

My code is:

```
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>
#include <xtensor/xcsv.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream in_file; 
    in_file.open("csv_file.csv"); 
    auto data = xt::load_csv<std::string>(in_file); 

    return 0;
}
```

When I inspect the `xt::xexpression` object `data` in my IDE, it appears correctly dimensioned and populated, but I can't find a way to read its elements in the code.

After poring through the *xtensor* documentation I am no wiser... Perhaps a pointer to a good introduction to *xtensor* might answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

After reading, `data` is simply an `xarray`: a multi-dimensional array, or in the case of CSV typically a matrix. On the matrix you can operate much like for example in NumPy. For example:

- `<<` allows you to print.
- `operator()(...)` allows you to get an item using row and column indices.
- `xt::view(data, ...)` allows you to get a 'slice'.

To be more specific consider this example:

```cpp
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <xtensor/xarray.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xview.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xio.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xcsv.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream in_file;
    in_file.open("csv_file.csv");
    auto data = xt::load_csv<int>(in_file);

    std::cout << data << std::endl;
    std::cout << data(0, 0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << data(0, 1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << xt::view(data, 0, xt::all()) << std::endl;
}
```

which for the following CSV file

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

prints:

```
{{1, 2, 3},
 {4, 5, 6},
 {7, 8, 9}}
1
2
{1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks for correcting the question and your answer. I tried data(1,2) in my IDE's immediate window but it kept rejecting the command, so I guess it has limitations.

Comment: I'm not sure about your IDE. If you try to add `data(1, 2)` in the code above and you'd compile it should simply work

Comment: The code data(1,2) compiles and works fine - thanks again. For some reason my IDE's immediate window doesn't recognise it. The IDE is MS Visual Studio 2017.